# Möbius map of two circles to half planes

Tags: complex-analysis, circles, conformal-geometry

I am very new to complex analysis and am having some trouble with finding a Möbius map that will take two unit discs to half-planes.

I don't have enough reputation to post images, but here is a link showing the initial setup:

http://s22.postimg.org/8sr5z3jlt/Skjermbilde_2013_07_24_kl_10_34_21_AM.png

I would like to map the red and green circles to half-planes such that the space between them becomes an infinite strip. Here is the what I would ultimately like to happen:

s18.postimg.org/kr82wowe1/Skjermbilde_2013_07_24_kl_10_41_24_AM.png

Following the instructions that I found here:

math.fullerton.edu/mathews/c2003/mobiustranformationmod.html

I learned that it is possible to construct a mapping by specifying the images of three points in the $z$-space under a Möbius mapping $S(z)$. I naively hoped that by specifying,

$S(i) = i, S(1 + 2i) = 1 + i, S(3i) = \infty$

I could force the boundary of the red circle to the upper half-plane. Using equation 10-21 on the website linked above, I derived that $S(z) = 2 / (z - 3i)$ This is indeed what happens to the red circle, as intended, but the green circle didn't go where I wanted it to (as expected). Here is an image showing this problem:

http://s15.postimg.org/4scrhqy7f/Skjermbilde_2013_07_24_kl_10_46_29_AM.png

So I'm hoping that someone here can help guide me to a better mapping that will take both circles to half-planes, which is what I really need.

Thank you.

Comment: You can't do it with Möbius transformations, because the boundaries of the two disks are disjoint, but the boundaries of two half planes have the point $\infty$ in common. Also, a strip between two half planes is simply connected, but the complement of two disks isn't.

Comment: I see. Here is alternative to my problem: Suppose instead of mapping two discs, I have only one disc whose center is on the imaginary axis and whose boundaries do not touch the origin (similar to the red circle in my images above). Instead of the green circle, I have a half-space that is Im[z] < 0 (denote this $A$). Is it possible to map the red circle to a half space under a mobius transformation while preserving the "half-spaceness" of $A$?

Comment: Ah, but I suppose my proposition runs into the same problem of half-conntectedness, doesn't it? That would seem to suggest that what I'm trying to do is impossible, no?

Comment: Yes, Möbius transformations are biholomorphisms of the entire Riemann sphere, so the topology remains unchanged.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

This will not work.
Since you want two disjoint circles to turn into lines, two points (one from each circle) must map to infinity.